# I use a-frame to apply a texture to a plane and nothing appears

Tags: textures, aframe, plane

I am starting with A-Frame. I have followed a tutorial to assign a texture to a plane.
Nothing appears, just a black plane.
That could be happening?
Thanks in advance
My code is the following:

````
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello, WebVR! • A-Frame</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello, WebVR! • A-Frame" />
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <img id="suelonormal" src="img/textura-suelo-normal.png" />
        <img id="suelo" src="img/textura-suelo.png" />
      </a-assets>

      <!--
      <a-plane
        material="color:white"
        rotation="-90"
        scale="15 15 1"
        repeat="5 5 1"
        src="#suelo"
        normal-map="#suelonormal"
        normal-texture-repeat="5 5 1"
      >
      </a-plane>
      -->
      <a-plane
        material="src:#suelo;repeat:5 5 1;normal-map:#suelonormal;normal-texture-repeat:5 5 1"
        rotation="-90"
        scale="15 15 1"
      >
      </a-plane>
      <a-sky color="blue"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>``` 
thank you in advance
````

Comment: Share full runnable example or it will be hard to help. I recommend https://glitch.com/~aframe

Answer (score -1):

I have found the problem: the texture was too heavy a file.
Thank you anyway